# Using JAX on large 2d array to find the largest n value

Tags: python, numpy, jax

I'm trying to use JAX to speed up my row and column-wise comparison/selection, I have a 2d array NxN, and each cell is a number, I'm trying to get the highest 4 number out of a row, then put a 1 in a different matrix C with the same index. These are two constraints: Each row and column can have maximum of 4 1s.
For a simpler example:

```
array a = [[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,7,8,9,10],
[11,12,13,14,15],
[16,17,18,19,20],
[21,22,23,24,25]]
C:
[[0,1,1,1,1],
[0,1,1,1,1],
[0,1,1,1,1],
[0,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0]]
```

We can not select the last 4 cells in the last row even that 4 cells' value are the highest, so we can only select the first one and put it in the C matrix

Here is what I tried with a different 2d array 8x8 and the correct C matrix, still an example, the real matrix is 4000x4000 and my code will take 10+ mins to complete

```
a_array = jnp.array([[0,3,4,0,0,12,19,22],
            [7,0,0,10,0,0,0,15],
            [12,0,0,15,16,19,0,31],
            [17,18,0,0,21,23,78,89],
            [22,2,78,0,0,1111,12,33],
            [123,0,122,10,14,0,50,60],
            [10,110,0,1231,0,110,0,61],
            [0,17,0,141,0,166,16,0]])

array_len = len(a_array)
c_matrix = jnp.zeros((array_len,array_len))
test_dict = {}
for i in range(array_len):
  test_dict[i] = 0
for i in range(array_len):
  for j in jnp.flip(jnp.argsort(jnp.array(a_array[i]))[-4:]):
    if test_dict[int(j)] < 4:
      if a_array[i][int(j)] != 0:
        test_dict[int(j)] +=1
        c_matrix = c_matrix.at[i,int(j)].set(1)
    if test_dict[int(j)] == 4:
      a_array = a_array.at[:,int(j)].set(0)
```

and the C matrix is:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

What I did here is first have a dict track of number of 1s in each column, if there are 4 1s already, update the 2d array with that column being all zeros, therefore, next for loop when jnp.argsort(...) trying to find the highest 4 cells, it wouldn't take the 0 into account, I also have a if check on cell == 0, to get rid of this edge case

```
jnp.argsort(jnp.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0]))[-4:]
```

output:

```
[4, 5, 7, 6]
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb when writing code with JAX, NumPy, or similar array libraries in Python is that if you're writing loops over array values, the result will be slow. Instead, you should try to express your logic in terms of native vectorized operations.

Here you can't vectorize the whole operation, because the number-per-column constraint means the output of each row depends on the output of all previous rows. In cases like this, [`lax.scan`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html) is a good option.

Here's how I would solve your problem with these things in mind:

```py
import jax

def scan_fun(count, row):
  row = jnp.where(count >= 4, 0, row)
  _, indices = jax.lax.top_k(row, 4)
  c_row = jnp.zeros_like(row).at[indices].set(1)
  c_row = jnp.where(row == 0, 0, c_row)
  count += (c_row > 0)
  return count, c_row

_, c_matrix = jax.lax.scan(scan_fun, jnp.zeros_like(a_array[0]), a_array)
print(c_matrix)
# [[0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]
#  [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0]
#  [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
#  [1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]]
```